# Manipulating BigIntegers in Java

Tags: java, biginteger

I have been working on a java program in which I need to calculate and store immense values into an array. So far, I get the value by plugging in an entered variable into an exponential function:

```
Math.pow(7,x);
```

I've decided to store the value into a BigInteger array, but I do not know how to store these regular manipulated values with the provided constructors BigInteger provides. For the 'x' value, I am actually using quite large numbers which launch the specified value over what longs can store. I seem to come full circle with every solution I think of...simply doing:

```
bigArray[i] = new BigInteger((long)Math.pow(7,x));
```

Does not work, since I am dealing with values larger than 100 as x. What can I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do

```
BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(7).pow(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

aioobe's answer already provided, suggesting using BigInteger.valueOf is correct, but I want to provide some additional information.

As he says:

```
BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(7).pow(x);
```

But lets also look at the Java documentation with regard to the "valueOf()" method:

"This "static factory method" is provided in preference to a (long) constructor because it allows for reuse of frequently used BigIntegers."

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf(long)

Comment: Thanks for the help! The additional information also helps

Answer (score 0):

Supply string as the param to BigInteger constructor E.g.

```
BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger("1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
```

In your case

```
 BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger("7").pow(x);
```

Comment: Most downvotes were on the previous revision of the answer that did not even include BigInteger::pow. Still, I don't understand why you recommend the use of the String based constructor.

Comment: Maybe, but it's common courtesy, if you downvote something, to hang around for a while to see if the poster improves the posting, which is what happened here.

Comment: @aioobe I am passing string because `long l = 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;` will not even compile but `BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger("1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000").pow(10);` will work like a charm

Comment: But the OP has not said anything about large bases. He even puts `7` as an example. The problem is when he varies `x` which he states goes as high as `100`. Neither of these numbers come close to requiring the String-based constructor.

Comment: This is all very true. The String constructor would also work, but for efficiency's sake just using the 'BigInteger.valueOf()' constructor will work just fine. Thank you all for your help!